# Why does this code behave differently in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript

In the browser and the NodeJS REPL the following prints `true`, but running as a file (ie. `node filename.js`) under NodeJS it prints `false`. Why?

All in non-strict mode, in the global context.

```js
var x = 1
console.log(window.hasOwnProperty('x')) // replace `window` with `global` for NodeJS
```

I am sure I am missing something obvious.

Comment: Node has module scope for what would be global (`window`) variables in a browser context.

Comment: I will accept that as the answer.

Comment: @52d6c6af Here is a [link](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global) to the docs, explaining this clearly.

Comment: That documentation is surely wrong. The top-level scope in Node _is_ the global scope - otherwise intrinsics would be out of scope in modules. It's just that variable declarations in modules occur within the scope of the module.

Comment: @52d6c6af It means "*The top-level scope [of module code] is not the global scope*", with "top-level" referring to the evaluated code, not the scope hierarchy of the whole program.

Comment: The top-level scope of module code is the global scope though. All the intrinsics and host objects are in scope as a result. Also, variable declarations at the top of modules are scoped to that module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They behave differently because Node.js wraps each module in a function, so variables are not scoped to the global object (`window`, `global` etc.):

> ## [The module wrapper](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v13.x/api/modules.html#modules_the_module_wrapper)
>
> Before a module's code is executed, Node.js will wrap it with a function wrapper that looks like the following:
>
> ```
> (function(exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {
> // Module code actually lives in here
> });
> ```
>
> By doing this, Node.js achieves a few things:
>
> - It keeps top-level variables (defined with `var`, `const` or `let`) scoped to the module rather than the global object.
> - It helps to provide some global-looking variables that are actually specific to the module, such as:
>
>   - The `module` and `exports` objects that the implementor can use to export values from the module.
>   - The convenience variables `__filename` and `__dirname`, containing the module's absolute filename and directory path.

Comment: How does this change with native modules?

Comment: @52d6c6af Not really. ES6 modules still have their own scope.